# Finding only the new rows added to a table

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following code which is supposed to get me only the new events added to the table from the last time i checked the table.

```
events=@browser.table( :id =>'table_events').tbody.rows
....
some code
....
events_new=@browser.table( :id =>'table_events').tbody.rows
events=events_new - events # not working !!
```

Im getting the fallowing error :

```
undefined method `-' for #<Watir::TableRowCollection:0x007fccb9ba2358> (NoMethodError)
```

I understand that the "-" predicate is wrong of course, but is there a method that does what i need or do i need to go over all the TableRowCollection and find the new rows manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting the `TableRowCollection` to an array, which does support subtraction:

```
events = events_new.to_a - events.to_a
```

That will work provided the elements have a useful `==` method defined - and it [looks like they do](http://rubydoc.info/github/jarib/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#%3D%3D-instance_method).

**Correction**: actually, because array subtraction is implemented using a hash table for efficiency ([view source here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2D) if you're curious), it is not the `TableRow#==` method that is important but the `TableRow#hash` method. Fortunately, it looks like Watir [implements that](http://rubydoc.info/github/jarib/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#hash-instance_method) as well.